# My game engine wont let me display a box! It is saying that It must be pygame.surface Not "Scene"

Tags: python, game-engine

I'm making a game engine with pygame! I'm trying to get it to render a Box, but it gives me a error...
Heres my code for 1:Engine:

```
import random
import pygame


pygame.init()

class Scene:
    def __init__(self,winwid,winhei,title):
        self.winwid = winwid
        self.winhei  = winhei
        self.title  = title

    def start(self):
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.winwid,self.winhei))
        pygame.display.set_caption(self.title)


class Block:
    def __init__(self,color,x,y,width,tallness,WIN):
        self.color = color
        self.x = x
        self.y = 0 - y
        self.width = width
        self.tallness = tallness
        self.WIN = WIN

    def draw_block(self):
        # Drawing Rectangle
        pygame.draw.rect(self.WIN, self.color, pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, self.width,self.tallness))

    def Update():
        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.display.flip()
```

```
2:Prgm/Test:import Mgine#ScenesSceneA = Mgine.Scene(330,430,"Tutorial 2 - A Box?","")Traceback (most recent call last):File "C:/Users/melti/OneDrive/Desktop/M-GINE/TUT2_TEMPLATE.py", line 7, in <module>MrBox.draw_block()File "C:\Users/melti/OneDrive/Desktop/M-GINE\Mgine.py", line 23, in draw_blockpygame.draw.rect(self.WIN, self.color, pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.tallness))TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not Scene#Sprites/ObjectsMrBox = Mgine.block((100,100,50),0,0,30,30)SceneA.start()MrBox.draw_block()Mgine.Update()
```

3:Error message:

I tried whats on the code right now, using the scene class.

Comment: Can you fix the indentation of your code, and the formatting of your exception message? I'm also not clear what the `1:`, `2:` and `3:` are supposed to mean.

Comment: when writing a question, try adding the code as it is on your side (indentation etc). Use a single code block for a single file, so that community users may copy/paste to help you solve the issue

Comment: @olirwin yeah it automatically did that when i tried using the thing to block the code sorry

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code a little modified in order to work also with some test code for you to test and modify it based on your desires:

```
# removed the import random since it's not used in this code
import pygame

pygame.init()

class Scene:
    def __init__(self, winwid, winhei, title):
        self.winwid = winwid
        self.winhei = winhei
        self.title = title
        self.screen = None

    def start(self):
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.winwid, self.winhei))
        pygame.display.set_caption(self.title)

    def update(self):
        pygame.display.update()

class Block:
    def __init__(self, color, x, y, width, tallness, win):
        self.color = color
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.tallness = tallness
        self.win = win

    def draw_block(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.win, self.color, pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.tallness))

# create instance of the Scene class
scene = Scene(330, 430, "A Box")
scene.start()

# create instance of the Block class and pass the scene's screen surface
my_block = Block((100, 100, 50), 0, 0, 30, 30, scene.screen)

# game loop
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    # fill screen (black)
    scene.screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    # draw the block
    my_block.draw_block()

    # update the display
    scene.update()

pygame.quit()
```